# an xlsm file is corrupted when dowloaded at client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, data-uri, xlsm

Pleasssse help me...
I have an xlsm file (excel with macro) on the server side (c#), and want to download it on client side (javascript, angularjs).
So.. in the server side controller I'm returning an HttpResponseMessage and in the client side - downloading it.

**The problem is that when opening the file that was downloaded, it is corrupted...**

I made a short test case to demonstrate the problem.

---

**Server side (c# ApiController):**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage exportDPs()
{            
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\excel\data.xlsm", FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "DPs.xlsm";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}
```

---

Client side (javascript, angularjs) :

```
$scope.exportDPs = function () { 
    $http({
        method: GET,
        url: '../Api/DPs/exportDPs',
    }).success(function (data) { 
        var file = data;
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(file);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", "data:application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF" + encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "DPs");
        link.click();                        
    })       
}
```

Comment: Check byte count to make sure number of bytes didn't change.  You streams are probably using default ASCII Encoding which is corrupting the file.  You need to use UTF8 encoding which will not change the file.  I would use following : StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"D:\excel\data.xlsm", Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Why are you prefixing the file content with a BOM (`\uFEFF`)? That's likely what is causing your problem.

Comment: Also, why not just have the code put the link to download into the `href` attribute and then call `.click()`. Trying to download the file and then serve it from the link as a data URI is needlessly complicating your problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding and trying to help!

Comment: Moshe Katz, when I give the URL of the file, I'm getting an error of  - Not allowed to load local resource. jdweng, the size of the file at the client side is OK, meaning the server side is not corrupting the file, only when dowloading it, the size becomes bigger, and the file is corrupted...

Comment: OK, so I took @Moshe Katz advise and changed the client code this way:                                                                                                                $scope.exportDPs = function () {     
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", "'../Api/DPs/exportDPs');
        link.setAttribute("download", "DPs");
        link.click();                        
    })       
} and now the file is not corrupted, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @mor Glad I could help. Since my comments appear to have solved your problem, I have turned them into an answer, which you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that you are prefixing the content from the server with a Unicode Byte-order mark (BOM) - `\uFEFF`. The BOM is only useful for text files, but XLSM is a binary file (to be more specific, it's a ZIP file of XML files).

However, instead of worrying about that, the best thing to do is to simplify your JavaScript so that you are downloading the file directly instead of trying to download the file in the background and make a data URI out of it.

This should do what you want:

```
$scope.exportDPs = function () {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "../Api/DPs/exportDPs");
    link.setAttribute("download", "DPs");
    link.click();                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. There is now somthing else thatdisturbes me - My URL needs to receive a complex parameter (array of objects). How do I do that in a URL?

Comment: @mor An array is typically passed in the query string like this: `?Values[]=1&Values[]=2&Values[]=3` for an array like this: `Values = [1,2,3]`. If you need something more complex than that, you have two easy options: 1) Create a JSON string and pass that in the query string. 2) Create a `form` element with a bunch of `input` elements inside it instead of an `a` element, and use `form.submit()` instead of `link.click()`. If you need more help with that, you should ask another question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that.